# How does the neo4j browser draw the object relationships?

Tags: neo4j, neomodel

When I run a query such as match (n) return n all of the nodes are returned, however, the relationships and how the nodes are connected does not appear to be in the response data. However, the graph manages to draw the full data model with relationships.

What is the browser doing to gather together this information, or am I missing how this can be obtained from the response data?

I have been using neomodel to query the data, however the inflate method walks the structure and returns too slowly. I would like to achieve a similar response without the need to walk the entire structure and was wondering what the recommended approach was?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're asking. The browser can render your results both in tabular and graphical format (there's an option in the result window).

Comment: What I meant was that the graphical format has data (the relationships) that the tabular format does not appear to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EDITED]

The neo4j browser has an "autoComplete" setting (labelled "Connect result nodes" in the latest version) that enables/disables querying for the relationships between the nodes in every result set. (Click on the gear icon in the leftmost panel of the browser to see the settings.)

In other words, the neo4j browser has to perform extra queries to get those relationships -- they are not returned for free when a query just asks for nodes.

If you are curious how autoComplete is implemented, [here is a link](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-browser/blob/master/src/browser/modules/Stream/CypherFrame/VisualizationView.jsx#L116) to some of the actual code.

Comment: Do you know how it forms those queries? It seems to manage this much fast than querying each node for its relationships in secession.

Comment: I have added a link to the actual code to my answer.