# How Does Neo4j Browser Also Show Relationships When Return Field Is Just Nodes?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-browser

In Neo4j Browser you see all edges between resultant nodes when you only queried for nodes.
For example,

```
MATCH (n:Greeting) RETURN n
```

shows nodes with the label 'Greeting' as well as all relationships between them.

This is true for other more complicated queries like

```
MATCH (n:Greeting {message: 'Hello'}) RETURN n
```

But when you use REST API you get only the nodes.
Actually this is the correct behavior and is obvious on resultant Table/Text/Code view.

That means Neo4j browser does some additional action when the result view is set to 'Graph.'

How can this be done?

Can we do this by just adding another statement, without modification of the original query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cypher query gives unnecessary relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45759688/cypher-query-gives-unnecessary-relationships)

Comment: Or rather, [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52447520/how-does-the-neo4j-browser-draw-the-object-relationships) is probably more relevant for what you want. Under the hood, when this option is checked, the browser executes a separate query to get the relationships between the nodes previously retrieved.