# Can't find the lightest path in Neo4j with cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to find the lightest path from node `a` to `e` in the following graph:

[image]

The result should be 13:

```
a -> b:  1
b -> c:  3
c -> d:  4
d -> e:  5 (take lighter edge)
----------
        13
```

I tried several examples, (e.g. https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/algorithms/shortest-path/) but can't find the right query.

```
MATCH (start:LocationNode{name:'a'}), (end:LocationNode{name:'e'})
CALL algo.shortestPath(start, end, 'weight',{write:true,writeProperty:'sssp'})
YIELD writeMillis,loadMillis,nodeCount, totalCost
RETURN writeMillis,loadMillis,nodeCount,totalCost
```

results in

```
╒═════════════╤════════════╤═══════════╤═══════════╕
│"writeMillis"│"loadMillis"│"nodeCount"│"totalCost"│
╞═════════════╪════════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│3            │3           │5          │12.0       │
└─────────────┴────────────┴───────────┴───────────┘
```

and

```
MATCH (start:LocationNode{name:'a'}), (end:LocationNode{name:'e'})
CALL algo.shortestPath(start, end, 'weight',{
nodeQuery:'MATCH(n:LocationNode) RETURN id(n) as id',
relationshipQuery:'MATCH(n:LocationNode)-[r:CONNECTED_TO]->(m:LocationNode) RETURN id(n) as source, id(m) as target, r.weight as weight',
graph:'cypher'})
YIELD writeMillis,loadMillis,nodeCount, totalCost
RETURN writeMillis,loadMillis,nodeCount,totalCost
```

results in

```
╒═════════════╤════════════╤═══════════╤═══════════╕
│"writeMillis"│"loadMillis"│"nodeCount"│"totalCost"│
╞═════════════╪════════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│3            │19          │4          │14.0       │
└─────────────┴────────────┴───────────┴───────────┘
```

Other queries like the following don't even return anything:

```
MATCH p=(LocationNode{name:'a'})-[:CONNECTED_TO*]->(LocationNode{name:'e'})
RETURN p as shortestPath,
REDUCE(weight=0, r in relationships(p) | weight+r.weight) AS totalDistance
```

I would like to see a query that returns '13' as solution and ideally displays the chosen path like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query:

```
MATCH p=(a:LocationNode{name:'a'})-[:CONNECTED_TO*]->(e:LocationNode{name:'e'})
WITH p, REDUCE(s=0, r IN RELATIONSHIPS(p) | s + r.weight) AS totalWeight
RETURN p, totalWeight
ORDER BY totalWeight
LIMIT 1
```

Returns this result:

```
╒══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╤═════════════╕
│"p"                                                                   │"totalWeight"│
╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╪═════════════╡
│[{"name":"a"},{"weight":1},{"name":"b"},{"name":"b"},{"weight":3},{"na│13           │
│me":"c"},{"name":"c"},{"weight":4},{"name":"d"},{"name":"d"},{"weight"│             │
│:5},{"name":"e"}]                                                     │             │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴─────────────┘
```

In the neo4j Browser, if you disable the [Connect result nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52447520/how-does-the-neo4j-browser-draw-the-object-relationships) option (at the bottom of the Browser Settings pane, which you can display by clicking the gear icon in the left panel), then the visualization will be:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you possibly know which algorithm is used in that query? Dijkstra, A*, ...?